# Show that $P(X)$ is a sigma algebra.

Tags: measure-theory

> Show that $P(X)$ is a sigma algebra.

First of all, surely this makes totally sense. But I'm wondering how you would actually prove this. How do you prove something as trivial that $P(X)$ is closed under complement. Or that it closed under countable uions ?

Comment: It *totally* makes sense. "is a sigma algebra" means that it satisfies the definition of a sigma algebra, so you would *actually* prove this by checking the axioms. You could "prove" those two "trivial" points by appealing to the definition of $P(X)$. After all, it's *important* that we're talking about $P(X)$ right? It's not true that *every* set of sets is a sigma algebra, so it must appeal to $P(X)$ somehow...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just work with the definitions. To show that $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is closed under complement, assume that $A \subseteq X$ is a subset of $X$, i.e. $A \in \mathcal{P}(X)$. Then,
$$A^c = \{ x \in X : x \notin A \}$$
is a subset of $X$ since every element of $A^c$ is in $X$. Thus, it follows that $A^c \in \mathcal{P}(X)$. The other definitions of a $\sigma$-algebra can be checked similarly.